# Right Period between two Java Dates

Tags: java, jodatime

I need help to get the Period between two Java Dates. I use JodaTime for the calculation but the result isn't correct.

Start: 11.11.2012 12:00
End: 16.12.2012 20:15
(German time standard)
Result musst be 5 weeks, 0 days, 8 hours and 15 minutes.

I try it with

```
Period period = new Period( start.getTime(), end.getTime() );
weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween( new DateTime( start ), new DateTime( end ) ).getWeeks();
days = period.getDays();
hours = period.getHours();
minutes = period.getMinutes();
```

and got 5w 5d 8h 15m.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the help but i think i use the JodaTime Period wrong. Off course is the output of 5w 5d 8h 15m right but what i want is more like this.

```
int days = Days.daysBetween( start, end ); // musst be 35 days
int weeks = ( days - ( days % 7 ) ) / 7;
days = days % 7;
```

Now is my result 5 weeks and 0 days. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: You might need a `% 7` for the `days`.

Comment: % 7 would do nothing because 5 mod 7 = 5 but thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(new Date(2012, 11, 11, 12, 00, 00));
    DateTime end = new DateTime(new Date(2012, 12, 16, 20, 15, 00));
    Period period = new Period(start, end);
    System.out.println("Weeks: " + Weeks.weeksBetween( new DateTime( start ), new DateTime( end ) ).getWeeks());
    System.out.println("Days: " + period.getDays());
    System.out.println("Hours: " + period.getHours());
    System.out.println("Minutes: " + period.getMinutes());
```

output is

```
    Weeks: 5
    Days: 5
    Hours: 8
    Minutes: 15
```

works like a charm
instead of `Weeks.weeksBetween` you can use next solution (using `PeriodType`)

```
PeriodType periodType = PeriodType.standard().withMonthsRemoved();
Period period = new Period(new Date(2012, 11, 11, 12, 00, 00).getTime(), new Date(2012, 12, 16, 20, 15, 00).getTime(), periodType);
System.out.println(period.getWeeks());
```

output is

```
5
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted my previous comment. You just didn't show the month field. But your current approach is less correct. adding 5 weeks to 11/11 will get you at 16/12, then adding another 5 days gets you at 21/12

Comment: Cool, you should just use the PeriodType approach in your original snippet, and you wouldn't need Weeks anymore, and produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For the output you want, I believe this is the solution :

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2012, 11, 11, 12, 0);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 12, 16, 20, 15);

    Weeks weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(start, end);
    Period period = new Period(start.plus(weeks), end);
    System.out.println("Weeks : " + weeks.getWeeks());
    System.out.println("Days : " + period.getDays());
    System.out.println("Hours : " + period.getHours());
    System.out.println("Minutes : " + period.getMinutes());
```

A Period will count a month instead of 5 weeks. So we first count the weeks between the two dates, and use a Period for the remainder.